# Flutter Stack loop - Clipping by previous stack elements?

Tags: flutter, dart, stack

I want to create some kind of "repeating" or "looping" Stack. Begin and end should overlap in reverse. Probably impossible with Stack itself.
Can I clip the later entries with the previous stack entries? That would create the desired effect...

Illustrated my problem/goal:

[image]

Example Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Color> colors = [
    const Color(0xFF2f5283),
    const Color(0xFF204b74),
    const Color(0xFF245c83),
    const Color(0xFF466a99),
    const Color(0xFF5d759d),
    const Color(0xFF52AFBF),
    const Color(0xFF49AB9B),
    const Color(0xFF419873),
    const Color(0xFF398564),
    const Color(0xFF317256),
    const Color(0xff40b725),
    const Color(0xff98e92e),
    const Color(0xfffff534),
    const Color(0xFFff9f34),
    const Color(0xFFff7d27),
    const Color(0xffe63a1f),
    const Color(0xffe8607e),
    const Color(0xffdf3caf),
    const Color(0xffa95ad0),
    const Color(0xffd567df),
    const Color(0xFFAF86F0),
    const Color(0xff4d59aa),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++)
        Transform.rotate(
          angle: pi * (i / colors.length) * 1.68,
          child: Transform.translate(
            offset: const Offset(80, 0),
            child: Material(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              color: colors[i],
                child: const SizedBox(
                  width: 70,
                  height: 70 * 1.618,
                ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Try it yourself:

https://dartpad.dev/?id=a8eb7fe2197b6f283e5e8b773f37a029&null_safety=true

Comment: I think you're on the right path with drawing the first two elements again on top of the stack using the last element's shape as a clip path. You might be able to clip it with a simple ClipRRect, but I'm not sure about the offset. You could certainly clip it with a CustomClipper.